# psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data into users table:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT NOT NULL, 
        id BIGINT NOT NULL, 
        xp INT NOT NULL
    )""")
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}") is None:
                if member.id not in bots:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, id, xp) VALUES ('{}', {}, {});".format(member, member.id, 0))
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
File "C:\Users\belog\hat_dispenser\main.py", line 58, in on_ready
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, id, xp) VALUES ('{}', {}, {})".format(member, member.id, 0))
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range
```

I tried to give the column "id" data types such as BIGINT, INT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL. But I still get an "integer out of range" error. How to fix it?

Comment: maybe you get the error because of the value of the field `xp`

Comment: You are going to need to `print` the value for the variable `member.id`  or look in the Postgres log to see what is being passed in.  Best bet it is something that is larger then `9223372036854775807`.

Comment: I checked and the maximum id was 910096720388583444. But even when I use the INT and SERIAL datatypes, I still get the "psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range" error.

Comment: You would as 910096720388583444 exceeds the limit(2147483647) for `int` and `serial`. You would need `bigint`/`bigserial`. Start with the premise that the error is telling you the truth and work backwards from there. Me I start with the Postgres log as that shows you what is actually hitting the database and has the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Do check whether this error is caused by the `id` column. Probably it's `xp`. My solution was to give the `BigInteger` type to an incorrect column.